# useRef value is getting reset when using rerender of react testing library

Tags: react-testing-library

I need to assert the function based on `ref` value on re-render of the component.

when I call the rerender of RTL resetPagination value is reset to false

added logs in the useEffect and found on rerender unmount is getting called.

```js
const resetPagination = useRef(false);

  useEffect(() => {
   
    if (resetPagination.current) {
      resetList();
      resetScroll();
      resetPagination.current = false;
    } else {
      updateList();
    }
    
  }, [filteredList]);// filteredList is the prop and updateFilter will change the fitleredList based on updated filters

const onFilterChange = (index, value, isSearch) => {
    updateFilter(index, value, isSearch);

    resetPagination.current = true;
  };
```

**Test case**:

```js
 it('reset list on resetPagination(filter change)', async () => {
    const { container, rerender } = renderComponent(pipelines);
    const filtersBtn = queryByDataId(
      container,
      `${migratePipelineFiltersDataIds.applyFilters}-button`
    );

    await act(async () => {
      await user.click(filtersBtn);
    });

    expect(updateFilterMock).toHaveBeenCalled();

    rerender(
      <PipelinesList
        pipelinesCount={pipelines.length}
        filteredPipelines={pipelines}
        updateFilter={updateFilterMock}
        updateSyncFrequency={updateSyncFrequencyMock}
        listFilters={[]}
      />
    );

    expect(MOCKED_LIST_ITEMS.resetList).toBeCalled();
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const resetPagination = useRef(false);
const [forceUpdate, setForceUpdate] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
  if (resetPagination.current) {
    resetList();
    resetScroll();
    resetPagination.current = false;
    setForceUpdate(false);
  } else {
    updateList();
  }
}, [filteredList, forceUpdate]);

const onFilterChange = (index, value, isSearch) => {
  updateFilter(index, value, isSearch);
  resetPagination.current = true;
  setForceUpdate(true);
};
```

Comment: is another state update is necessary? updateFilter func will change filteredList prop